# What does this complicated sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

Would to god I could strip you   of life and breath and ship you down to the House of Death   as surely as no one will ever heal your eye,   not even your earthquake god himself!’

Comment: Where did you get this awesome sentence?

Answer (score 3):

I will loosely break it down:

Would to god = I sincerely wish

I could strip you of life and breath = I could kill you

and ship you down to the House of Death = (more emphasis - means "kill you" again)

as surely as no one will ever heal your eye = as entirely as you cannot stop being blind (in one eye?)

, not even your earthquake god himself!’ = in a way that your Gods cannot help you at all.

Very clearly (and basically) I means: "I *really* want to kill you..."

Hope that helps.

Comment: @username901345 I added a more direct and simple clarification. Yes I am a native speaker (and speak other languages too)

Comment: Of course no one will heal you! To the same degree I wanna kill you?

Comment: @username901345 Yes, I suppose so. "To the extent that no-one can heal you, I want to kill you".

Comment: I believe this is from Homer's Odyssey, and is what Odysseus says to Polyphemus (the Cyclops - hence the reference to one eye) after Polyphemus has been blinded. He claims that Poseidon, his father, may restore his vision.

Comment: @long Thank you, sir. I thought it looked familiar - or at least famous.

Answer (score 3):

It is from Book Nine of [The Odyssey](http://teachers.sduhsd.k12.ca.us/cfox/documents/Book%20Nine%20Cyclops896-913.pdf)

Odysseus has blinded the Cyclops Polyphemus, And taunted him as he and his men set sail to leave the blinded Cyclops. The Cyclops answers him, stating that his father, Poseidon, also known as the earthquake god, will heal him (restore his vision) if he prays to him to do so.

Odysseus fires off his parting shot:

> Heal you! Would to god I could strip you of life and breath and ship you down to the House of Death as surely as no one will ever heal your eye, Not even your earthquake god himself!

An interpretation is:

*"I'm sorry I only **blinded you**. I wish I could kill you and send you to Hades; I wish it as surely as you are blind, and will stay that way."*

Then, Polyphemus prays to his father:

> Hear me – Poseidon... grant that Odysseus, raider of cities... never reaches home.  Or if he’s fated to see his own people once again and reach his well-built house and his native country, let him come home late and come a broken man, Let him lose all companions, and return under strange sail to bitter days at home.

Which is exactly what happens - it takes Odysseus 10 years and many awful losses to find his way back home.

Comment: so. The possibility of his eye being unhealable is very certain. To the same degree of certainty, I wanna kill you! Is this OK?

Comment: Yes. As surely as he will stay blind, Odysseus wants to kill him and send him to hell.